# Ethernet not working after removing GPU

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, gpu, file-server

So, I am having an issue where my Ubuntu Server (v18.04.3) no longer wants to connect to the internet. It was working fine before I took out my gpu to sell. I have googled to my hearts content and have found many people with the same or similar issues. I have tried all the remedies that have been suggested, but to no avail. Could someone give me a bite more insight as to how I might fix this?

Links I have tried:

- [Why is my ethernet interface called enp0s10 instead of eth0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-is-my-ethernet-interface-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0)
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html
- [Wrong predictable network interface name in Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437011/wrong-predictable-network-interface-name-in-debian)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/826325/how-to-revert-usb-wifi-interface-name-from-wlxxxxxxxxxxxxx-to-wlanx/826614#826614
- [Internet not working without gpu installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353674/internet-not-working-without-gpu-installed)

Outputs from commonly asked commands:

- ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2160 bytes 154368 (154.3 KB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 2160 bytes 154368 (154.3 KB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions0
```

- ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_left forever
    inet ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preffered_left forever
2: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:cb:8a:bf:3c:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

EDIT: Spelling/grammar

Comment: Instead of the old `/etc/network/interfaces`, Ubuntu 17.10 and newer are using `netplan` for their network configuration storage by default. Is there a file named like `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` in your system? What is in it?

Comment: Yes, there is, and I have renamed the `enpXs0` (X being a number that I changed to see if it would work). Unfortunately, that did not show any results.

Comment: This is what was inside it
`'network:' 'ethernets:' 'enp6s0:' 'dhcp4: true' 'version: 2'`

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/jLUE0Q9f

Answer (score 4):

When you removed the GPU, the PCIe bus configuration of your system changed, causing the bus location of your NIC to change. This change is reflected in the PCI IDs in the `lspci` listing, and also in the "predictable network interface names".

Your NIC used to be named something like `enp?s0`; now it is `enp6s0`.

Edit the netplan YAML file to change the name of the NIC to match what it is now:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Change `enp?s0` (where ? is some number unknown to me) to `enp6s0` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save & exit.

(Based on your comments, perhaps you have already done this.)

Then run `sudo netplan apply`. (This might be the only thing you're missing.)

Comment: Yea, I kept editing and rebooting the server since it doesnt take so long. I didnt try the `sudo netplan apply`, so maybe that will fix it.

Comment: I have now tried this method and it does not work, I am still unable to connect to the internet.

Comment: This answer *did* work to solve the problem on my Ubuntu 22 server, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> When you removed the GPU, the PCIe bus configuration of your system changed, causing the bus location of your NIC to change. This change is reflected in the PCI IDs in the lspci listing, and also in the "predictable network interface names".
>
> Your NIC used to be named something like enp?s0; now it is enp6s0.

So what if I don't have the `netplan` command available?

`networkctl` will be available on most Linux distros. The command below will give you the current link being used (ether in this case).

```
# networkctl list

IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           n/a         unmanaged 
  2 enp5s0           ether              n/a         unmanaged
```

The `enp5s0` value in this example is the new link that will need to replace `enp6s0` in the configuration below.

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp6s0 inet manual
```

Note: You will want to change all instances of `enp6s0` in this file.

Once that is change is written, restart your networking and the link should be online.